# Test performing on counts

Tags: r, testing, statistics

In R a dataset `data1` that contains `game` and `times`. There are 6 games and `times` simply tells us how many time a game has been played in `data1`. So `head(data1)` gives us

```
game  times
1     850
2     621
...
6     210
```

Similar for `data2` we get

```
game  times
1     744
2     989
...
6     711
```

And `sum(data1$times)` is a little higher than `sum(data2$times)`. We have about 2000 users in `data1` and about 1000 users in `data2` but I do not think that information is relevant.

I want to compare the two datasets and see if there is a statistically difference and which game  "causes" that difference.

What test should I use two compare these. I don't think Pearson's `chisq.test` is the right choice in this case, maybe `wilcox.test` is the right to chose ?

Comment: that's more a CV question as it is about a statistical question and not programmation